# Petrol station in Folkestone before boarding the Eurotunnel train

Tags: uk, automobiles, local-knowledge

Where is the most convenient petrol station to fill up if we have some spare time before boarding the Eurotunnel train? Is it possible to fill-up after checking-in?

We will be driving from London.

Comment: If you are driving on petrol. It might be worthwhile to wait until you are in France: http://www.drive-alive.co.uk/fuel_prices_europe.html

Comment: Please be aware that officially Eurotunnel don't like cars with tanks that are absolutely full to the brim. On one of the filling stations nearest to the French terminal, Eurotunnel had applied stickers to the pumps warning people that there was a risk that the tank overflowed, thus causing a fire risk. This petrol station has since been demolished and I haven't seen stickers on any other petrol station's pumps.

Answer (score 6):

[Stop 24](http://motorwayservicesonline.co.uk/Folkestone) is located just minutes from the Eurotunnel and the Port of Dover. It is the UK's largest service station and until recently it was the newest. It also doubles up as a 'Port Early Arrival Facility', meaning that anyone early for their ship or a train can stop by and rest before heading onwards.

As well as a petrol station, it has other facilities including a KFC & Subway if you are hungry.

Address:    Stop 24 Services,
Stanford Intersection,
Hythe,
Kent
CT21 4BL

Comment: Apparently 21 km is "just minutes" ...

Answer (score 3):

Once you have entered the complex there is zilch facilities for re-fuelling. Either fill up before entering or wait until you get to France - there is a petrol station on the left as you leave the complex. BTW be wary about carrying reserves - the EuroTunnel site explains better [what you can carry as a reserve](https://www.eurotunnel.com/uk/carriage-of-reserve-fuel-containers/).

Comment: Care to add a link to and a quote of the site you mention?

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps shows the following, where the grey pin (top left) is for Eurotunnel, Folkestone:

[image: Folkestone]

Ignore the Esso pin (Eurotunnel Service Station), it is a facility designed for trucks. The Tesco Station is bound to be the cheapest, though going via it would add about three miles to your journey (assuming you have satnav and don't get lost!). It is open 24 hours and next to a supermarket, in case of any last minute shopping requirements.

If you do have some time to kill you might appreciate a slightly longer diversion down to the coast. The BP pin on the A259 (which I think used to be Murco) is right on the beach but would add about another five miles.